# Быстрый поиск в 1 млрд строк

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки, файлы

Есть несколько текстовых файлов. Размером от 50 Мб до 5 Гб. Общей сложностью примерно 700-1000 млн строк. Все текстовые файлы лежат в одной папке, их имена известны заранее.

Пример файла:

```
c4ca4238a0b9233d5fcc509a6f75849b.z001   6b3u3v65vu26u3bv6u
3d5f728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c.z001   4cv5b7nm86ompmp9n6
ecc3d5fe4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3.z001   1p864nv6rwye653565
a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b73d5f22c.z001   vb4484nb4646v46bvu
e4da3b7f3d5f2345d7772b0674a318d5.z001   vb75in86o486onb7i3
1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc.z001   v66v4664u64uvu6464
8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543.z001   4g6v6464buv64ubv64
c9f0f895fb98ab9159f51fd0297e236d.z001   54vb567n7u35gf6b6h
45c48cce2e2d7fbdea1afc51c7c6ad26.z001   g64u34u73h5635g636
```

Необходимо найти все строки, которые содержат ключевые символы и выгрузить эти строки в отдельный файл. Список ключевых символов находится в отдельном файле keys.txt. Выгружать нужно не всю строку, только с 1 символа до первого знака табуляции или пробела.

Пример файла keys.txt:

```
3d5f
0000
сссс
```

Необходимо найти все строки, которые содержат ключевые символы и выгрузить эти строки в отдельный файл. Список ключевых символов находится в отдельном файле keys.txt. Их количество может достигать 100 шт. Выгружать нужно не всю строку, только с 1 символа до первого знака табуляции или пробела.

Т.е. для моего примера правильный выходной файл должен иметь вот такой вид:

```
c4ca4238a0b9233d5fcc509a6f75849b.z001
3d5f728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c.z001
ecc3d5fe4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3.z001
a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b73d5f22c.z001
e4da3b7f3d5f2345d7772b0674a318d5.z001
```

Необходимо обрабатывать подобные файлы как можно быстрее. Желательно, чтобы работало и в Windows и в *nix системах.

Какой алгоритм следует использовать? Может кто-нибудь помочь написать пример?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111139/discussion-on-question-by-kapi----1--).

Answer (score 13):

Насколько я понимаю, поиск должен выполняться по каждым запросам однократно, так что:

1. Очевидно, что ничего быстрее чем прочитать файлы один раз и выполнить одновременно поиск, ничего быть не может. Впрочем, можно поиграться с memory mapped files - теоретически это может повысить скорость чтения.
2. Внутри каждой строки надо осуществлять поиск. Можно пытаться строить деревья поиска, если обычный поиск недостаточно эффективен, но я по вопросу этого не увидел. Если искомых строк не очень много, они не очень длинные и не сформированы специально, чтобы завалить обычный алгоритм поиска, его должно хватить.
3. Можно разделить программу на 2 (при необходимости и более) потоков: один считывает данные, другие их (при необходимости параллельно) обрабатывают. Если все данные на одном физическом диске, то считывать в несколько потоков смысла нет, потому что наоборот диск будет работать медленнее. Если на разных, то можно параллелить по физическим дискам.

В общем-то это всё, дальше надо реализовывать и пробовать на конкретных данных.

> Имеет ли смысл распараллеливать чтение если файл находится на SSD?

Тоже нет. Главное не косячить с размером блока при чтении (например, использовать блоки по 1048576 байт) и SSD выдаст свою максимальную скорость на 1 поток считывания (замеры есть в комментариях).

Comment: @dIm0n, нет. Речь идёт о потоковой обработке - читаем и одновременно ищем. При этом количество чтений с диска - одно.

Comment: А в теории есть возможность разбить файл на куски и обработать файл в несколько потоков? Я перед собой вижу несколько плюсов данного решения. Обработанный файл удаляется и на очередь становится новый. ........ Как по мне, сейчас ничтожно мало одноядерных процессоров, поэтому работать в одном потоке и решать задачу я думаю не будет являться самым эффективным решением. *(Это чисто теоретический вопрос, быть может я не прав и далек от реальности)*

Comment: @MoloF разбить-то можно, но смысла нет, так как в описанном процессе узкое место это чтение с диска. Если имеем обычный диск HDD или SSD, то увеличение количества потоков, которые обращаются к диску, только снизит общую скорость чтения. То что есть много процессоров или ядер никак не помогает быстрее читать с диска. Общая производительность ограничена скоростью считывания данных с диска .

Comment: @RomanKonoval, у меня скорость копирования с SATA SSD в NUL от 450 до 530 МБ/с (проверял в [Unreal Commander](https://x-diesel.com/?7MtnP)'е). Это довольно близко к заявленным максимальным 600 МБ/с из характеристик, причём, у меня на компьютере это вызывает зависания других программ и скачкообразные перемещения мыши вместо плавных (из-за файла подкачки на том же ssd). На M2 или PCI по идее должно было быть больше. Понятия не имею, как можно было получить 210 МБ/с. Или дело в том, что чтение на питоне имеет какие-то скрытые замедления? И не забывай звать тех, к кому обращаешься через `@`.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что Unreal Commander как раз и копирует параллельно. Еще зависит от фрагментированности файла - random read даже заявленный в разы медленнее чем sequential. Плюс важно что еще запущено, у меня система не в спокойствии. Я 210MB/s получил с помощью `dd if=/path/to/30Gb of=/dev/null` на MacOS, а `dd` внутри делает простое чтение и запись системными вызовами без каких либо оптимизаций. А 700 MB/s это когда запускаю параллельно копирование больших файлов командами dd.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, я уверен, что там нет параллельного копирования. Тем более при том, что я взял один файл на 28 гигов. При чтении важен размер блока. Насколько я понимаю, у dd по умолчанию 512 байт, что очень неэффективно. Вот замер в bash под Windows 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q0tc.png - добавление параметра `bs=1048576` повышает скорость в 10 раз до тех же 460 МБ/с.

Comment: Точно. Увeличение буфера до 1MB дает скорость 1.2GB/s, а это, проверил, есть заявленная скорость последовательного чтения. Распараллеливание, естественно, ускорения не дает, а немного уменьшает, но думаю, погрешность измерения выше.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, ну во, 1.2 GB/s - это ж вообще шикарно. А если после распараллеливания получается примерно так же, то и параллелить смысла нет :) Дописал в ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111199/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----1--).

Answer (score 11):

Программирование - наука экспериментальная... Так что ставим эксперимент... - [см. исходники тут](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/tree/master/quest/1157786).

Первая программа создала за 3 с половиной минуты 10-гиговый файл со случайными строками и файл ключей, причем каждая пятая строка в файле данных обязательно содержала тот или иной ключ.

Вторая программа читает эти 10 гиг и заносит в отдельный файл первые части строк, в которых найдены ключи. Читает построчно, проверяет тупо, испытывая все 100 ключей, пока не найдет или пока ключи не закончатся (это для тех, кто через 40 строк кода продраться не может...).

По мне - достаточно жесткое испытание. Машина у меня далеко не премиум класса :), но менее чем за 11 минут собрала гиговый файл с найденными строками.

Считаю это "**ужас-ужас-ужас!**" надуманным, как таковой особой проблемы просто нет...

По заявкам зрителей :)

Если искомых строк нет вообще - обработка чуть больше 2 минут.
Если все строки - искомые, то примерно 10 минут. Вероятно, потому что теперь не требуется в 90% случаев прогонять весь поиск, по всем 100 ключам.

Применение алгоритма Ахо-Корасик сократило время работы первоначального эксперимента (там, где было 11 минут) вдвое.

Испытывать по 10 раз и считать среднее - у меня терпения не хватило :)

Comment: По идее, самый медленный поиск - это когда вхождений вообще нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как сказать. Тормозят ведь дисковые операции! Впрочем, сейчас сделаю, дополню ответ...

Comment: Вы не находите, что без описания подхода, алгоритма и кода, этот ответ "ни о чем" ?

Comment: @Kromster Вы не находите, что в первой строке дана ссылка на код?

Comment: *“Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”*

Comment: @Kromster Ответ на вопрос дан в ответе, код - не более чем справочный материал (там вы ответ на вопрос не найдете). Если вы считаете ответ некорректным - обозначьте его тревогой, пусть решают модераторы.

Comment: Опасение я высказал, модераторов тут ни к чему звать. Если вы не хотите сделать ответ "я сделал, у меня норм" лучше - дело ваше )

Comment: @Kromster  Нет, я не хочу забивать ответ кодом. В данном случае код не является существенным для ответа. Ответ дан полный и развернутый. Добавление сюда тривиального кода его никак не улучшит.