# Как на самом деле работает multi-read exclusive-write?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, файловая-система, io, multiprocessing

Всем привет.

Пожалуйста, расскажите, по возможности, подробно как на самом деле работает Multi-read Exclusive-Write (MREW), а то я все не могу понять с точки зрения физики процесса.

Объясню свой вопрос на примере многопоточного чтения и записи текста в файл.

MREW предполагает, что выполнение операции чтения может происходить несколькими потоками, а запись - только одним, чтобы исключить взаимных блокировок.

Однако, с точки зрения HDD, все эти операции будут выполняться последовательно, потому что головка диска не будет параллельно считывать различные блоки памяти.

Например, читаем 10 потоками файл размером 5 Гб, каждый поток со своим смещением. С точки зрения кода все ясно, но для жесткого диска - диск не сможет писать параллельно, так как головка диска просто физически на это не способна, как я полагаю.

Отсюда следующие вопросы:

1. Значит нет никакой многопоточного чтения? Или как достигнуть этого эффекта?
2. Или диск читает блоками вне зависимости полностью файл занимает блок или только часть?
3. Тогда какой размер этого блока, чтобы максимально быстро считывать или записывать в файл?

Помогите пожалуйста с описанием процесса

Comment: Так вам нужно объяснение работы MREW или работы HDD? Напрямую они никак не связаны. | Читать/писать можно не только с диска, а из источников данных в памяти, сети и пр.

Comment: Видимо из-за того, что я не понимаю как работает процесс выгрузки в память файл с HDD, я не могу понять как может работать MREW. Меня интересует именно файловый ввод/вывод с HDD

Comment: забудьте про файлы и подумайте про оперативную память. Например, если у вас есть массив и вам надо его читать и писать в него.

Comment: Так операция выгрузки в оперативную память, что то стоит и она наверное последовательная, да и выгружать в оперативную память 5 Гб файла неразумно. А если размер файла 100 Гб, как тогда? Его не выгрузишь в оперативную память

Comment: `забудьте про файлы`, вам надо узнать как файловая система работает или как многопоточные читаели\писатели?

Comment: Хорошо, перефразирую вопрос, как быстро прочитать текстовый файл размером 50Гб 100 потоками, посчитать сколько слов больше 6 букв, и эти слова записать в другой файл используя MREW. И чтобы это было многопоточность чтение, а не вход в критическую секцию и 99 потоков простаивают и ждут когда первый поток прочитает свою часть

Comment: @JzD ок, а причём тут MREW?

Comment: И почему именно 100 потоками?

Comment: Это просто конкретный пример, чтобы было понятно что объяснять. В чем тогда смысл Multi-read если по факту он его последовательно читает?

Comment: Файл эффективней читать одним потоком. Обрабатывать файл в памяти уже можете как вам удобно, хоть producer-consumer используйте

Comment: @PavelMayorov в том, что я полагаю, что чтение с диска и MREW идущие друг за другом операции. Но я могу ошибаться и я усомнился в этом, вот и пытаюсь выяснить это. Поэтому и пришёл за помощью

Comment: @tym32167 тогда возникает вопрос, какой размер файла лучше прочитать, чтобы добиться максимальной быстрой выгрузки в память? Или скорость чтения пропорциональна длине буфера? Грубо говоря — один байт/одна миллисекунда

Comment: @PavelMayorov при том, что я хочу добиться минимального времени при максимальной эффективности операции чтения-обработки файлов больших размеров

Comment: Вы можете считать, что скорочть чтения файла обратно пропорциональна количеству чтений. Самое быстрое - прочтитать файл ра одно чтение. Чем больше чтений - тем медленней. Поэтому, если у вас большой буфер - то вы читаете быстро, если маленький - медленно.

Comment: Почему мне кажется, что HDD - это что-то из прошлого, и уже мало кто ими пользуется? У меня что дома, что на работе, что в датацентрах их нет вообще, при чем уже года 3 живого харда не видел, минимум. Другими словами, смысл оптимизировать свежий софт под хард, если очень скоро харды уйдут в прошлое, как ленточные накопители?

Comment: @aepot а в чем разница между оптимизацией под HDD и под SSD\SSHD\etc?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну SSD же может быстро читать мелкими блоками, моментально "прыгая" на произвольные позиции диска. А HDD быстро "прыгать" не умеет, для него предпочтительно последовательное чтение.

Comment: @CrazyElf я про то, что минимизация количества чтений - это универсальный прием, он сработает хорошо не зависимо от типа накопителя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для MREW и целей его использования не имеет значения параллелизм исполнителя. Есть разделяемый ресурс (массив в памяти, запись в БД, файл на диске). К нему доступаются параллельно много потоков. Операция доступа неатомарна и занимает какое-то время. Нужно обеспечить целостность ресурса и консистентность данных, которые видят потоки.

Для этого предусмотрены два вида блокировок. Если потоку нужно только читать, то он захватывает блокировку на чтение, перед тем как собственно читать. Она гарантирует, что никто не поменяет массив (запись в БД, файл) пока мы читаем. А чтение может занять какое-то время. Это может быть не одна операция, а несколько. Может перемежаться с операциями от других исполнителей. Другие потоки могут параллельно захватить такую же блокировку и читать.

А вот писатель не сможет захватить эксклюзивную блокировку пока кто-то держит блокировку для чтения. И поменять не сможет, пока все не отпустят свои блокировки.

Так что не важно, что скажем диск может делать только одну операцию чтения в конкретный момент (хотя это не так, диски могут переупорядочивать операции с целью оптимизации). Но даже если так, то все равно чтение большого файла будет состоять из множества мелких чтений, между которыми может "вклиниться" запись. И для этого нужен механизм, который будет синхронизировать доступ.

Теперь, что касается быстрого чтения. Распараллеливать смысла особого [нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157786/%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2-1-%d0%bc%d0%bb%d1%80%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba/1157798#comment2008508_1157798) если у вас обычный диск, а не RAID. Главное не читать маленькими кусками, блоки используйте побольше. Точный размер покажет тестирование с вашим железом.