# локировка потоков лишь с одним триггером на включение

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть массив который должен читаться рядом потоков асинхронно, а так же есть один метод который дописывает данные в массив и иногда удаляет от туда данные. Мне нужно что бы как только данный метод сработал все чтецы становились в очередь и дожидались завершения модификаций с массивом. Подскажите как это сделать ?

Использовать лок или семафоры не могу так как в данном случае доступ к массиву будет синхронным, а мне нужно синхронизировать доступ к нему лишь в момент его модификации. Подкажите есть ли что то вроде лока или же семафира который мог бы включаться лишь из одного метода и высвобождаться лишь этим методом ? Пишу на C# .net core 5

## Дополнено :

Есть массив типа double около 100 000 записей может и больше, копировать не вариант так как скорость очень важна.

Есть потоки по номерам {1,2,3,4}
Все потоки асинхронно читают данный массив просто читают без права изменений. Их нельзя ставить в очередь иначе вся система полетит или как минимум будет не так функционировать как нужно...

Есть метод который добавляет данные в массив, и удаляет их. К примеру в результате его работы массив вырос на 6 новых эллементов.

Задача, поставить на паузу все потоки которые работают с данным массивом, что бы они дождались пока поток модифицирующий массив, не закончил с ним работать.

```
class MyObject
    {
        readonly List<double> data = new();
        
        public this[int ind] 
        {
            get
            {
                return data[ind];
            }
        }
        
        public void Modify(double[] newValues)
        {
            data.AddRange(newValues);
        }
    }
```

Это самый простой демонстрационный объект о котором идет речь. Вот мне нужно в индексаторе дожидаться пока не закончит работу метод Modify. И ждать лишь в том случае если метод Modify был запущен. Иначе все потоки смогут асинхронно брать значения через индексатор.

Comment: Смотрите https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=net-5.0 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207153/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-multi-read-exclusive-write/1207156

Comment: Массив большой? Нельзя вместо модификации массива, создать новый массив? И что значит модификации? Вы свою задачу описали сильно абстрактно, соответственно и советы получите абстрактные.

Comment: @tym32167 Дополнил более конкретным описанием.

Comment: Как часто и каким объемомо пишете? Массив у вас будет не более 100 000 экземпляов? Вам точно надо остановить все потоки, даже если они читают область массива, куда не ведется запись? Изменение должно быть атомарным? Потоки на чтение читают какими то порциями?  Что если сделать второй массив с ReaderWriterLock на каждую ячейку? Или вам именно весь массив надо блокать?

Comment: @tym32167 запись непроизвольна. причем может быть так что по мимо добавления в конец массива, будут добавлены так же записи в начало массива. Так же раз в 15 минут будет добавление данных в конец массива и в полночь обрезание массива до определенного значения. некоторые потоки берут лишь последние элементы, некоторые весь массив целиком. блокать каждый конкретный эллемент массива не нужно.

Comment: во первых, я не знаю что это `readonly <double> data = new();` - но это явно не массив.

Comment: @tym32167 это лист

Comment: во вторых, блокирование массива целиком может вам помочь, но скорость явно упадет при этом

Comment: @tym32167 то что целиком блокировка помодит то я знаю но как раз жтого то и не нужно. Я делаю реализацию индикаторов для торговых роботов. один индикатор могут использовать 10 роботов. но они должны будут подождать когда он будет рассчитываться. индикатор должнен быть длины не более заданной по этому массив будет обрезаться.

Comment: вы назвали список массивом, хотя это абсолютно разные вещи. Например, массив можно читать и писать одновременно, массиву все равно и все будет хорошо, если читатели читают область, которая не меняется. Список нельзя читать и писать одновременно, он под капотом может пересоздать массив. Список вообще не является потокобезопасной коллекцией.

Comment: что вы ещё неверно назвали я не могу знать, потому могу только посоветовать юзать ReaderWriterLock(Slim) для всей коллекции.

Comment: @tym32167 приделаетесь сударь, лиск в повседневности тоже массивом называют часть, речь идет в целом о коллекции данных. Полная локировка не подходит.

Comment: Именно эту проблему решает стандартный класс ReaderWriterLockSlim. Проще - на весь массив

Comment: ни в коем случае не придераюсь, я наоборот вам разъяснил, почему ничего не могу посоветовать больше, так как не понимаю в принципе вашу задачу, а ваши пояснения больше запутывают. ReaderWriterLock(Slim) как раз позволяет иметь несколько читателей или оджного писателя. То есть данные будут заблокированы во время записи полностью, но доступны для чтения несколькими потоками, когда запись не ведется. Имейте только ввиду, что List не является потокобезопасной коллекцией, хз как он отреагирует на несколько читателей.

Comment: буду прбовать блогадарю.

Comment: @tym32167 благодарю, попробую

Comment: Вероятно, достаточно просто взять одну из потокобезопасных коллекций. [Thread-Safe Collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/), [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-5.0). Дополнительные блокировки при этом не нужны.

Comment: Смотрите дубликат, там пример реализации коллекции с использованием шаблона проектирования Reader/Write Lock, реализованного в .NET классе `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Это именно то что вам нужно.