# Разбить на многопоток. Python

Tags: python

Программа ищет слово в нескольких файлах (Поиск слова "Yes", пример содержания файла "0 sp Yes yes S". Необходимо переделать код под многопоток, но опыта с этим в пайтоне не имею. Особенно не очень представляю, как переделать читание файлов. Буду рад любой помощи.

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\project1'
word = 'Yes'
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower()[-4:] == '.txt':
            with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as in_put:
                if not word in in_put.read():
                    print('-')
                else:
                    in_put.seek(0)
                    for row, line in enumerate(in_put):
                        if word in line:
                            count += 1
print(f'Найденных слов: {count}')
```

Comment: Так что Вы уже делали с multiprocessing, threads и asyncio? Что не получилось с ними?

Comment: Делать чтение файлов многопоточным - бессмысленно, поскольку все равно упрется в скорость чтения файлов с винчестера. Если, конечно,это не учебная задача.

Comment: @Chorkov сферическая задача в вакууме и реальная жизнь могут отличаться. Представьте, что у Вас сделан mount по scp раздела на удалённом сервере, а подключение по 9400  И таких точек монтирования куча. И вот уже задача играет другими красками :)

Comment: Ещё как вариант диск может быть SSD и тогда в чтение и позиционирование вообще упираться не будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf будет, уже обсуждалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157786/%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2-1-%d0%bc%d0%bb%d1%80%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba/1157798#comment2010478_1157798

Answer (score 1):

Выигрыш этой затеи сомнителен в плане производительности - в основном всё упрётся в скорость чтения файлов и, в случае HDD, процесс может даже замедлиться, потому что HDD долго "перескакивает" с одного файла на другой.

Но можете попробовать переделать обход файлов на генератор, а потом "скормить" этот генератор в `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, написав отдельную функцию для подсчёта нужных штук в одном конкретном файле. Потом собираете результаты `Pool.map` и складываете их. Всё.

Answer (score 1):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


def open_file(filename):
    files = {
        'file1': '0 sp Yes yes S',
        'file2': 'No Yes',
        'file3': 'No 0 S sp',
    }
    return files.get(filename, '')


def find_words(filename, word):
    file_content = open_file(filename)
    return file_content.count(word)


WORD = 'Yes'
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:  # Max workers up to threads in your pc
    features = [executor.submit(find_words, filename=f, word=WORD) for f in ('file1', 'file2', 'file3')]

count = sum(feature.result() for feature in as_completed(features))
print(f'Найденных слов: {count}')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]